# Correctly filling augmented svg path created by D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to use D3 to create augmented svg-pathes and filling them.
Augmented pathes are pathes, that contain multiple parts using different interpolation methods. Have a look at the following example (execute the code to see the svg):

```js
p1 = [
  [10,10],
  [10,190],
  [190,190]
];

p2 = [
  [190,190],
  [50,50],
  [190,20]
];

p3 = [
  [190,20],
  [190, 10]
];

p4 = [
  [190,10],
  [100,20],
  [10,10]
];

  var svg = d3.select('svg')
              .attr("width", 200)
              .attr("height", 200)
              .attr("viewBox", "0 0 200 200");

  var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear");
  var spline = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis");
  
    svg.append("path")
     .attr("d", function(){
       return line(p1)  + spline(p2) + line(p3) + spline(p4)
     })
     .attr("fill", "none")
     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
     .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
</svg>
```

If I now fill the created path (changing fill from "none" to "purple" for example), I get an undesired result:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="190" width="190">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="purple" d="M10,10L10,190L190,190M190,190L166.66666666666666,166.66666666666666C143.33333333333331,143.33333333333331,96.66666666666666,96.66666666666666,96.66666666666666,68.33333333333333C96.66666666666666,39.99999999999999,143.33333333333331,29.999999999999996,166.66666666666666,24.999999999999996L190,20M190,20L190,10M190,10L174.99999999999997,11.666666666666664C160,13.333333333333332,130,16.666666666666664,99.99999999999999,16.666666666666664C69.99999999999999,16.666666666666664,39.99999999999999,13.333333333333332,24.999999999999996,11.666666666666666L10,10"></path></svg>
```

The shape is not recognized as one shape and thus not filled correctly. (By the way: it works when using only one spline and only one linear interpolated part.) One possibility to solve that problem, would be to remove the unnessesary movement commands inserted by D3. However, I can't believe, that this is the only solution. There must be a simpler and cleaner solution. Probably I'm misinterpreting how to use D3. Can anyone give me a clue?

Edit:
What I expect the filled shape to look like:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="190" width="190">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="purple"
d="M10,10L10,190L190,190L166.66666666666666,166.66666666666666C143.33333333333331,143.33333333333331,96.66666666666666,96.66666666666666,96.66666666666666,68.33333333333333C96.66666666666666,39.99999999999999,143.33333333333331,29.999999999999996,166.66666666666666,24.999999999999996L190,20L190,10L174.99999999999997,11.666666666666664C160,13.333333333333332,130,16.666666666666664,99.99999999999999,16.666666666666664C69.99999999999999,16.666666666666664,39.99999999999999,13.333333333333332,24.999999999999996,11.666666666666666L10,10"></path></svg>
```

Comment: "The shape is not recognized as one shape and thus not filled correctly." Can you explain what you mean with a picture of the correct, expected filling of the shape ?

Comment: @DamienFayol added the expected result, thanks for visiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just concatenate the paths together.  Each one starts with a `move to` command (`M10,10` or something like that).  This will produce an "open" path that you can't be filled correctly.  Easy fix, is to just remove the `move to` command on all but the first path:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg>
  </svg>
  <script>
    p1 = [
      [10, 10],
      [10, 190],
      [190, 190]
    ];

    p2 = [
      [190, 190],
      [50, 50],
      [190, 20]
    ];

    p3 = [
      [190, 20],
      [190, 10]
    ];

    p4 = [
      [190, 10],
      [100, 20],
      [10, 10]
    ];

    var svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 200 200");

    var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear");
    var spline = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis");

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", function() {

        var s1 = line(p1),
            s2 = spline(p2),
            s3 = line(p3),
            s4 = spline(p4);
            
        s2 = s2.substring(s2.indexOf("L"), s2.length);
        s3 = s3.substring(s3.indexOf("L"), s3.length);
        s4 = s4.substring(s4.indexOf("L"), s4.length);  

        return s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
      })
      .attr("fill", "purple")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thank You for your solution, but as I stated, I already was aware of it and hoped to find a better solution (without the need to modify the result returned by D3.js). This is why I will only give You an upvote. I guess there is probably no solution to my problem (apart from writing a patch for D3 ;).

Comment: @LordBo, opps, I should read more carefully.  In my experience with `d3` I don't think you'll find a more elegant way to do this.